# 415 Unsupported Media Type with html5 video tag on live server?

Tags: html, apache, html5-video, mime-types

I am working on simple HTML site where I am putting one video. It works on localhost but invisible on live server.

It shows me this error: `415 Unsupported Media Type`

```html
<video autoplay muted loop class="embed-responsive-item" id="autovid" width="100%" >
     <source src="images/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

**`.htaccess`**:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/x-flv .flv
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
AddType image/x-icon .ico
```

Comment: This is server configuration issue. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366816/apache-ignoring-mime-type for more explanation